# Is it okay to set OpenSSL to use SSLv3 as a client from a compatibility standpoint?

Tags: ssl, openssl

Exactly as the title states: Is it okay to set OpenSSL to use SSLv3 as a client from a compatibility standpoint?

I have recently run into websites which don't support the SSLv2 helo, therefore I was thinking that from a compatability standpoint it would be better to use SSLv3. Ultimately, Im asking whether or not it is true that SSLv3 will be more compatible than SSLv23 (i.e. SSLv23_client_method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have to support whatever the websites require that you need to talk to, but ideally at this stage you should forget all about SSlv2 and SSLv3 with the V2 handshake. You should be using TLS as the primary protocol and SSLv3 as a fallback, with the RSA and 256 bit cipher suites given priority.

Comment: so you're saying that that method will be compatible with most websites?